# AspNet Core on Azure App Service peaks to 100% CPU and app gateway load balancer not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, garbage-collection, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

We have few of our internal business services hosted on an isolated ASE in Azure. 
These services run on a medium app service plan with 2 instances.

This environment has been in production and use for little more than a month now and has been performing fairly well apart from the occasional sudden CPU spike to 100% in one of the instance which bring down the services.

We don't have auto scaling setup but have 2 instances running all the time.

The services are `aspnetcore` webapi and the runtime is dotnet core 2.0.

 Every time I have come across this issue in the last couple of weeks I have not been lucky enough to login to kudu and get a process dump to investigate further. The business are literally behind my back to get the service up and running as quick as possible and the easiest route is to restart one of the faulting service or swap slots with a pre-prod environment.

Access to the ASE are also restricted from our network and makes it all the more difficult for me to switch to a WiFi and then go through jump boxes to login to kudu, I had asked our Ops engineer to get me the dump when this issue is reported but he has not been listening to me either, mostly for the same reasons as me not able to do it myself.

All exceptions I can see in Application Insights are due to the service themselves going down and there are no exceptions there which can cause the issue in the first place(at least I've not found it yet)

This lead me to take few guess and look for metrics, the only thing raising my
suspicions is garbage collection. I don't see any sudden spike in GC graphs as well, each time the service is re started the graph is fairly a straight line(24 hours) but increases day by day and ends up like below.

But the working memory is a sinusoid graph letting me think there are no memory leaks. But is the above graph over 3 days normal? 

The drop is when I restart the service. But all services have a similar trajectory even the one that has not gone down. 

 I am not sure if this is a problem with an individual service or an environment configuration I have overlooked.

The API endpoints are simple CRUD operations and publish events to a service bus topic after each operation. There is a static `HttpClient` instance used to fetch data from another service. Apart from that there are no unmanaged resources and the DB connections are always wrapped in `using` statements.

I understand I would need a process dump to investigate further but my biggest concern is why is the application gateway(load balancer) not sending traffic to the healthy instance. Because of the gateway going unhealthy cloudflare returns a `502` response to clients using the api.
MS support haven't been able to help and have not answered if we have our load balancers working correctly.
The average number of requests is about 50-60 per minute.
CPU runs at less than 10% apart this sudden surge.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the backend is pegged at 100% CPU and is unable to respond to Application Gateway health probes. When such an issue occurs, were you able to verify, using Backend health logs, the health state of your backends? If both backend instances were unhealthy, it would explain the 502s. If one of them was healthy and responding to probes, then new requests sent to Application Gateway would indeed flow to the healthy instance. If you suspect that is not the case then please reply back with subscription id, gateway name and approximate time window of incident for us to take a look.

Comment: both the backend instances were not unhealthy..only one. but our services went down nevertheless